# Tool for drawing and colouring shapes easily

Tags: geometry, reference-request, visualization

I want a tool to easily make geometry diagrams. For example, say I wish to overlay two circles, and then fill their overlap with the color red, whilst coloring other areas with other colors? Let's say I want to make a triangle with curved sides and a flat bottom side; that could be done in no time with the right tool. I could insert a square and then delete circles from its upper two quadrants. To be more clear, here are the list of features I'd like:

1. A gallery of shapes that can be sized and colored as one wishes.
2. The ability to fill any area enclosed by lines with a color.
3. The ability to draw lines between highlighted points on shapes, like the centers of their sides, their corners, points between the quadrants of the circumference of a circle (allowing the drawing of diameters), etc.
4. The ability to insert text into the diagrams.
5. Is free to use.

To give examples of close contenders: Draw.io has all features except number two. Microsoft paint and sketchpad has all features except number three. Does an app that has all features exist?

Comment: Microsoft paint?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Given my initial, vague description, that would work. However, for what I am actually looking for, microsoft paint is a tad too basic (though it was close). Draw.io is also close, but it lacks the color fill feature. See my edit for my now clarified question.

Comment: I use calculators from this site https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/list-of-online-calculators-for-math-physics-earth-and-other-curiosities.970262/. In the case of graphics, I let programs like GeoGebra or MatheGrafix or Graph do the main job and eventually, add comments or colors via screenshot and mspaint.exe.

Comment: I am also interested in such an app. If no such app / program / tool exists, then I agree that there is a gap in the market for it.

Comment: @MariusS.L. Did you happen to download MatheGrafix off of this site: https://www.heise.de/download/product/mathegrafix-69939/download I am asking because I wonder if it is safe to download.

Comment: @user110391 heise.de is the standard page in Germany for downloads of this kind literally for decades. It is safe.

Comment: I use **Mathigon** and **GeoGebra**. Each of them has advantages that the other does not.

Comment: @MariusS.L. Thank you!